# Symfony 2 ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, symfony

I downloaded symfony 2.0.9 without vendors. After that I executed `php bin/vendors install` to install the vendors. The process went ok. But when I executed `http://localhost/project/web/app.php` I received

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

I don't know what is happening.

If I comment the line `$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();` in `app.php` the response changed to 200 OK.

Does anybody know what the problem is? I am on PHP 5.3.9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe I have the same issue; Firefox thinks for a moment then fails with the message, "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." If you view the source, however, you will notice a bunch of warning and fatal error notices - do you have PEAR installed and is it accessible from your system path?

Comment: Checked my versions - running Wampserver 2.2c, PHP 5.3.9, using Symfony 2.0.10. I have PEAR installed and `php.ini` has been updated to reflect its path - and still I have the same error as you.

Comment: What happens when you use app_dev.php instead? What does symfony log says?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the vendors are not installed correctly, try first to clear the cache for prod with php app/console cache:clear --env=prod (app.php), Try those different solution [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with symfony2 but not with PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001232/err-connection-reset-with-symfony2-but-not-with-php-script?rq=1) hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue right today. The problem was the memory_limit parameter in php.ini. I've set it to 16M for another project, and it seems that with 16Mb, Symfony crashes. I've switched it back to 128M and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue on windows 10 --> apache2 ---> httpd.conf file
Added following lines in httpd.conf file

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 524280
</IfModule>
```

Basically issue is limited thread stack size. I have increase this.
Hope someone will find it useful.